# Can modules be added to the Python search path (e.g site-packages dir) using symbolic links on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, symlink

I tried to create a symbolic link in the Python site-packages directory using the `mklink /D` syntax (on a Windows 7 machine). Unfortunately the module is not found when using import clause. When I copy the module physicaly to site-package directory, it works OK. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible on Windows?

I am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it on Windows 7 using Python 2.7, and it works. Here are the steps I followed.

1. open a windows command prompt with necessary privileges
2. cd to the site-packages directory

   cd c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
3. create the link

   mklink /D modulename c:\path\to\module\real\location\modulename

Comment: Great, it works under python27. I am not sure if it works under 2.6 though.

Comment: huum. It does not seem to work for me (two PCs both with python27 on Win7). But I did not want to copy the entire folder like the case above. I copied only __init__.py and few other py files that I need. Then, /D option did not work.  But /H option worked.